# Hay day revive others' tree

Tags: hay-day

I have tons of trees. Apple trees. Cherry trees. I build tons and tons of them.

I put ! sign and within less than 5 minutes someone always revive the tree.

How do others know that I have put that ! sign?

I didn't even say that on facebook and the one reviving my trees are not my friend.

Perhaps visitors scan my whole farm and look for ! sign but why would they do that?

I want to help revive others' tree too so I get thank you letter.

How would I do that?

Comment: There are Derby tasks to "help 27 farmers before the end of the Derby". I'm currently hunting for farms with help requests, and finding none. :(

Answer (score 1):

I used to do this too. You can visit anyone in hay day in general without adding them as friends. Now, how they visit you? Simple, visitors can come via newspaper ads you have put up, or via some friends you have. You can visit them the same way too!